# How do I make sure you are using latest version of third party tools without manually checking?

Tags: dll, version

We use ton of third party libraries(Mostly GitHub hosted) and tools and its pretty hard to keep track of their latest version. It would be great to have some tool to manage it without too much of manual periodic check about their latest version.